# Create altenate user to key pairs ssh login

Tags: root, users

I am using AWS EC2 and using a key pair with Putty for access. However in case I somehow lose access to the key pair I would like an alternative login. For now I created a password for root, but I am not sure what the best practice would be. I also encountered a situation where I was installing a web application and I could not cd into a directory with the regular user, and sudo reported it could not use cd. So in that case I also created a pw for root. Your guidance will be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: `cd` can't be run *directly* with `sudo` because it's a shell builtin - but you can start a root shell with `sudo -s` (or `sudo -i` for a login shell) - there's really no need to unlock the root password for that

Comment: great, thank you